# Laravel home page is not displaying correctly

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, composer-php, homestead

I have my laravel project installed using homestead and I connect to it via SSH using Vagrant(on Windows). The first time I launched my project there was a message indicating i have an error in my public/index.php file indicating that directory specified in 'require' on 14 line is not found it was written like this

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

then I just replaced this line of code with directory of welcome.blade.php file (require .../welcome.blade.php) (the home page of Laravel) and this page displayed each time I went to my project website but there was another message displayed saying

> Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in
> /home/vagrant/code/myProject/bootstrap/app.php on line 14.

I think that is because of the laravel version installed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfXi9.png)

What I find quite suspicious is that I haven't got env file and vendor folder inside my project folder. vendor folder was located in AppData/Roaming/Composer folder by default. I just moved that folder to my project folder

Comment: Got it. The problem was with `laravel new` command. I should've used `create project laravel/laravel` command instead. With this command `.env` file and `vendor` folder will be present in a project folder

Answer (score 0):

First thing, Revert the changes within public/index.php back to how it was. That deals with autoloading and bootstrapping the laravel application and should never really be changed.

Now ssh to your vagrant box and within the laravel project, run `cp .env.example .env` and then edit the newly copied .env file to have all your details for DATABASE and APP_NAME.

Next, go into your project, and run `composer install` and this will install all the needed dependencies from the composer.json file.

And lastly, from within your project, you should now run `php artisan key:generate` to generate the APP_KEY.

This should fix your issue. 
I would also advice that you look carefully over the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs